# Making a for-each cycle inside a for-each cycle work in a XML file

Tags: xml

Using this meniu.xsl file file:

```
<html xsl:version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <body style="font-family:Arial,helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:12pt; background-color:#EEEEEE">
        <xsl:for-each select="meniu">
            <div style="background-color:#00FF00;color:white;padding:4px">
                <span style="font-weight:bold;color:white">
                    <xsl:value-of select="laikas"/>
                </span>
                <br>&#160;</br>
            </div>
            <xsl:for-each select="patiekalas">
                <br>&#160;</br>
                <div style="background-color:teal;color:white;padding:4px">
                    <span style="font-weight:bold;color:white">
                        <xsl:value-of select="pavadinimas"/>
                    </span>
                    <span style="margin-left:10px;font-size:10pt">
                        <xsl:value-of select="kaina"/>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div style="margin-left:20px;margin-bottom:1em;font-size:10pt">
                    <xsl:value-of select="aprasymas"/>
                    <span style="font-style:italic">(<xsl:value-of select="kalorijos"/> kalorijų)</span>
                </div>
                <br>&#160;</br>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </body>
</html>
```

I can run this meniu.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="meniu.xsl" ?>
   <meniu>
    <laikas>PUSRYČIAI</laikas>
    <patiekalas>
        <pavadinimas>SUMUŠTINIAI SU SŪDYTA LAŠIŠA</pavadinimas>
        <kaina>12 Lt</kaina>
        <aprasymas>skrudinta balta duona, žalias padažas, alyvuogės, lašiša, citrina</aprasymas>
        <kalorijos>650</kalorijos>
    </patiekalas>
    <patiekalas>
        <pavadinimas>KAIMIŠKA KIAUŠINIENĖ</pavadinimas>
        <kaina>11 Lt</kaina>
        <aprasymas>kepti kiaušiniai, rūkyta šoninė, šviežios daržovės, skrudinta duona</aprasymas>
        <kalorijos>880</kalorijos>
    </patiekalas>
</meniu>
```

But once I edit the meniu.xml to double everything in the meniu tag, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="meniu.xsl" ?>
<meniu>
<laikas>PUSRYČIAI</laikas>
<patiekalas>
<pavadinimas>SUMUŠTINIAI SU SŪDYTA LAŠIŠA</pavadinimas>
<kaina>12 Lt</kaina>
<aprasymas>skrudinta balta duona, žalias padažas, alyvuogės, lašiša, citrina</aprasymas>
<kalorijos>650</kalorijos>
</patiekalas>
<patiekalas>
<pavadinimas>KAIMIŠKA KIAUŠINIENĖ</pavadinimas>
<kaina>11 Lt</kaina>
<aprasymas>kepti kiaušiniai, rūkyta šoninė, šviežios daržovės, skrudinta duona</aprasymas>
<kalorijos>880</kalorijos>
</patiekalas>
</meniu>
<meniu>
<laikas>PUSRYČIAI</laikas>
<patiekalas>
<pavadinimas>SUMUŠTINIAI SU SŪDYTA LAŠIŠA</pavadinimas>
<kaina>12 Lt</kaina>
<aprasymas>skrudinta balta duona, žalias padažas, alyvuogės, lašiša, citrina</aprasymas>
<kalorijos>650</kalorijos>
</patiekalas>
<patiekalas>
<pavadinimas>KAIMIŠKA KIAUŠINIENĖ</pavadinimas>
<kaina>11 Lt</kaina>
<aprasymas>kepti kiaušiniai, rūkyta šoninė, šviežios daržovės, skrudinta duona</aprasymas>
<kalorijos>880</kalorijos>
</patiekalas>
</meniu>
```

The page (meniu.xml) stops loading. How do I edit the .xsl file so 1) it loads 2) I can run the xml file with everything inside  tag doubled?

I looked at [For-each inside for-each](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30401946/for-each-inside-for-each) by the way, and it was of some help, but I couldn't fix the issue I described here.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's nothing to do with XSLT; your XML is not well-formed. You can't have an XML document of the form

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<menu>..</menu>
<menu>..</menu>
```

You need to add a wrapper element:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<menus>
 <menu>..</menu>
 <menu>..</menu>
</menus>
```